# Showing $f$ is injective if $g \circ f$ is the identity

Tags: functions, logic

So we have $f: X \to Y$ a function between two sets.

I'd like to show that f is injective if and only if it exists a function $g: Y \to X$ such as $g \circ f = 1_X$ (here $1_X$ is the identity on $X$).

Usually, to show that one function is injective, I'd have to show that for all $a$ and $b$ in $X$, such that $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a = b$.

However, I'm not sure how to address this problem when we have a composition of functions.

Anybody could help?

Thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099699/left-inverse-in-f-a-iff-injective-proof

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical notation. For now, I have edited your question to use that.

Comment: thank you all, I somehow missed that ∘ = 1 means that the composition is an identity function, which is obviously injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a) = f(b)$ then $(g \circ f)(a) = (g \circ f)(b)$. If $g \circ f = 1_X$ (the identity on $X$), then what does this give you?

Answer (score 0):

If a composite $g\circ f$ is injective, then the first component $f$ is injective.

In your case, $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}$, and $\operatorname{id}$ is injective

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2 \in X$ then $g[f(x_1)]=g[f(x_2)]$ i.e $x_1=x_2$ as $g\circ f$ is Identity function. Therefore, $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually, to show that one function is injective, I'd have to show that for all a and b in X, such that f(a)=f(b), then a=b.

You do it the exact same way.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function.

Claim: If there exists a function $g:Y\to X$ so that $g\circ f = 1_x$ then $f$ is injective.

Pf:  Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$.  Then

$g(f(a)) = g(f(b)$.

But $g\circ f = 1_x$ so

$1_x(a) = 1_x(b)$ so $a = b$.

So $f$ is injective.

...

The other direction is almost easier....

Assume $f:X\to Y$ is injective.

Define $g:Y\to X$ via:  For any $y \in Y$, if there is an $x_y\in X$ so that $f(x_y) = y$ then let $g(y) = x_y$.  This is well, defined; as $f$ is injective there is no ambiguity-- if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$ and $\{x\in X|f(x)=y\}=\{x_y\}$ has one elements.)  If there is no $x \in X$ so that $f(x) = y$ then let $g(y)$ be.... well... anything.  Let $x_0\in X$.  If there is not $x$ so that $f(x) = y$ then let $g(y) = x_0$.

Claim:  $g\circ f(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$.

Pf: If $x \in X$ then $f(x) \in Y$ and $f(x) = f(x)\in Y$.  So by definition, there does exist an $x_{f(x)}\in X$ where $f(x_{f(x)}) = f(x)$; it is ... $x$ itself... so $g(f(x)) = $ then value $x_{f(x)}$ where $f(x_{f(x)})= f(x)$ and that is... $x$.

So $f:X\to Y$ is injective implies there is a function $g:Y \to X$ so that $g\circ f = 1_x$.