# Discrete Mathematics, proving a composed function is bijective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given a function $f : X \rightarrow X $
It is known that $f^5 = I$ where $I(x) = x$ (The identity function)
I need to prove that $f$ is bijective (Injective and Surjective)

$f^n = f \circ f \circ f ...\circ f$

I've tried many ways such as finding out whether or not $x_1, x_2 \in X$ exist such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ but it did not help as the function was composed with itself (5 times) and I got stuck...

Comment: @cmk and so basically the whole expression is: $f(f^{-1}(x))$ ? I hope I understood

Comment: Well, if a function has a left and right inverse, then that will be the genuine inverse of the function. So, here $f^{-1}=f\circ f\circ f\circ f.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f^4$ is both a left and right inverse for $f$. The existence of a left inverse proves the $f$ is injective, and the existence of a right inverse proves that $f$ is surjective. You can find both of these on this site (e.g. [Left inverse in $F_{A}$ iff injective proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099699/left-inverse-in-f-a-iff-injective-proof) for left inverse).

To make this more self-contained, here is how one shows injectivity: if $f(x)=f(y),$ then we know that $f^4(f(x))=f^4(f(y)).$ That is, $f^5(x)=f^5(y).$ But, $f^5$ is the identity, so $x=y.$ Surjectivity is similar.

Comment: Do I need to prove that $f^4$ is an inverse of $f$ ? or it's known as a fact? - thanks I saw the links now

Comment: One can prove that if a function has a left and a right inverse, then they must be the same, and they are the inverse of the function.

Comment: But, all that you need to prove (per your question) is infectivity and subjectivity. The left inverse gives the former, and the right inverse gives the latter.

Comment: I see, because f(g(x)) = x then it must say that g(x) = $f^{-1} (x)$ ?

Comment: No, that only guarantees that $f$ is surjective. But, the other also gives that $f$ is injective. Thus, it's bijective. Also, an inverse of a function $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a function $g:X\rightarrow X$ so that $f\circ g=id_X$ and $g\circ f=id_X.$

Comment: Here, $g=f^4.$ $\ $

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, I am stuck on the surjectivity, is it currect to prove like this: let $y \in X$ then $f^5 (y) = y$ because $f^5 (x) = I = x$ and thus we found a proper x, which is $f^4(y)$ such that $f(f^4(y)) = y$ and so it's surjective?(onto X) thank you

Comment: That is correct (could probably be written more cogently, though)!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f^4$ is the inverse of $f$ whence it follows that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: But how do I know if it's the inverse I mean what is the rule that being satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

If you learned about inverses, then what the other users posted will suffice. If not, to show it's one to one, 
Assume $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.
Apply $f$ 4 more times on both sides and you will see that $f$ is injective. 
To show $f$ is surjective, let $y$ be an arbitrary element of the codomain. We know that $f^5(y) = y$. So, can you think of a way to decompose $f^5(y)$ to achieve the desired result?